# Use Microsoft Azure tenantId to lookup the domain of an external party using the Microsoft Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, graph

I have a set of values sent back for the Microsoft Azure Graph API on Azure and I want to do a reverse lookup to either find a users by User Id GUID or Tenant ID using the Graph API?

```
        "user": {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxd0d8",
            "displayName": "External user",
            "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxd0d8"
```

}

Comment: The tenant Id is the Azure AD instance to which the user belongs and does not uniquely identify a user. To get more details on a user when you have both the tenant and the user Ids (as well as permissions to user's tenant), you can perform a cross-tenant query. See: https://blog.ciaops.com/2020/04/18/using-the-microsoft-graph-with-multiple-tenants/

Comment: Do you just want to find users by user id?

Comment: Yes, but they could be in any tenant?